# How to use t4 template in MVC action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, t4

I am trying to use t4 template, so that i don't have to type view names in action link,but i am not sure how to set this up.

In my layout page I have a link:

```
 <ul class="menu" >
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Profile", MVC.Profile.Views.Index)</li>
  </ul>
```

So I was expecting it to load: `http://localhost:1234/Profile/Index` but instead it is loading  `http://localhost:1234/Login/~/Views/Profile/Index.cshtml`

Can some body help with this?

Default Route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it !

The action link code should be  `<li>@Html.ActionLink("Profile", MVC.Profile.Index())</li>`

Thanks